# クラスの型を関数の引数に渡したい

Tags: c++

下記のようにクラスが定義されているとき、main関数内からfunc関数の引数として「クラスの型」を指定することで、func関数内で任意のオブジェクトに対してmake_sharedをしたいのですがどのようにfunc関数を設計すれば宜しいでしょうか？

```
class BaseClass {
    //　メンバー変数
    // メンバー関数
};

class FirstClass : public BaseClass {
};

class SecondClass : public BaseClass {
};

class ThirdClass : public BaseClass {
};
```

```
void func()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<CLASS_NAME>;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    func(CLASS_NAME);　// FirstClass, SecondClass, ThirdClassのいずれか
}
```

Comment: 目的に合っているか/使えるかは不明ですが、こんな情報が何かの参考になるかも。[ランタイム型情報](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/cpp/run-time-type-information?view=msvc-170), [typeid 演算子](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/cpp/typeid-operator?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

テンプレート関数にして、引数ではなく型引数を受け取ることでしょうか。

```
template<class ClassName>
void func() {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<ClassName>();
}

int main() {
    func<FirstClass>();
}
```

どうしても丸括弧で記述したいならマクロ定義も追加すれば実現できます。

```
#define FUNC(CLASS_NAME) func<CLASS_NAME>()

int main() {
    FUNC(FirstClass);
}
```